# How to repeat values in pandas data frame column at specific indices?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a following df with two cols **seq_no** and **val**:

```
     seq_no     val      expected_result
 0      21        0         0  
 1      21        0         0
 2      21        1         0
 3      22        1         1   #seq_no changed
 4      22        1         1
 5      22        6         1
 6      23        6         6   #seq_no changed
 7      23        7         6
 8      24        7         7   #seq_no changed
 9      24        12        7
10      25        12        12   #seq_no changed
11      25        12        12
12      25        13        12
```

It is seen that the seq_no is repeated in 2 or more rows, What is wanted is to create a new column **expected_result** where, whenever seq_no is changed, at that index whatever value is under **val** is checked and that value is repeated in **expected_result** untill again the **seq_no** is changed.

The **expected_result** col illustrates what I want. Basically it is required to get the indices where the seq_no is changing, then at those indices check the values under **val** and then finally repeat those values until seq_no is changed or next index from idx_list is encountered.

I could find the list of required indices, but stuck with further operations.

```
 i = df.seq_no.values

 df["bool"] = np.append(True, idx[:-1] != idx[1:])
 list1 = df[df["bool"] == True].index.tolist()
 list1
```

Following is the list of indices where seq_no are changing:

```
 Out [ ] : list1
         [0, 3, 6, 8, 10]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`df.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html), followed by [`df.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html#pandas.Series.reindex) with `ffill`:

```
In [1363]: df[df.diff().fillna(1)['seq_no'] > 0].val.reindex(df.index, method='ffill')
Out[1363]: 
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      1
4      1
5      1
6      6
7      6
8      7
9      7
10    12
11    12
12    12
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

This is identical to your `expected_output` column.

You can just assign this to a new column in place:

```
df['expected_output'] = ...
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED Please can u have a look at the updated part, and see what can I do ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @kshama That isn't a good idea. You make the question unreadable by making edits to it. I recommend you open a new question.

Comment: @COLDSPEED https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526511/how-to-create-new-column-by-comparing-values-of-other-columns Please Check

Comment: @kshama Why did you delete [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526511/how-to-create-new-column-by-comparing-values-of-other-columns)? If my helped you, please mark it accepted... instead of deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use map by creating a grouped series of min values i.e

```
df['new_expected']=df['seq_no'].map(df.groupby('seq_no')['val'].min())
```

Output:

```
    seq_no  val  expected_result  new_expected
0       21    0                0             0
1       21    0                0             0
2       21    1                0             0
3       22    1                1             1
4       22    1                1             1
5       22    6                1             1
6       23    6                6             6
7       23    7                6             6
8       24    7                7             7
9       24   12                7             7
10      25   12               12            12
11      25   12               12            12
12      25   13               12            12
In [483]:
```